# Evaluating the double integral $\int_0^\infty d a \int_0^\infty d b\ \frac{ \sin(x a) \sin( y b ) }{a+b}$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Consider the double-integral
$$
F(x,y) := \int_0^\infty d a \int_0^\infty d b\ \frac{ \sin(x a) \sin( y b ) }{a+b} \ .
$$
By playing around in Mathematica I have come to believe that the above evaluates to
$$
F(x,y) \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{\pi}{2(x+y)} \ .
$$
How would one prove this result?

**EDIT:** I've been able to evaluate the $a$-integral, showing that the above is equal to
$$
F(x,y) = \int_0^\infty db\ \sin(by) \bigg[ \text{Ci}(bx) \sin(bx) + \frac{1}{2} \cos(bx) \big( \pi - \text{Si}(bx) \big) \bigg] \ ,
$$
where $\text{Ci}$ and $\text{Si}$ are the cosine integral and sine integral functions, respectively. From here I cannot make progress.

There is a symmetry in the order of integration (*ie.* the above would look the same if I did the $b$-integral first). It is curious that the function seems to depend on $x+y$: I don't see how this dependence falls out of the definition of $F$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire See my edit above.

Comment: I think it follows the trick considering $\frac{1}{a+b}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}exp(-(a+b)c)dc$, using Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ax \sin bx}{a+b} da db =
\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin ax \sin by ~ da ~ db ~ e^{-(a+b)t}~dt$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} dt\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin ax ~e^{-ta} da \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin by ~  db ~ e^{-tb}\right)$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{xy}{(t^2+x^2)(t^2+y^2)}dt= \frac{xy}{y^2-x^2} \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{t^2+x^2}-\frac{1}{t^2+y^2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2(x+y)}.$$
Note that:
$$J=\int \sin ax ~e^{-ta} da=\Im \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(t-ix)}=\frac{x}{t^2+x^2}$$

Comment: +1. maybe a sentence or two justifying the order of integrations?

Answer (score 1):

$$F(x,y)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(xa)\sin(yb)}{a+b}da\,db$$
$u=xa,da=du/x$ and $v=yb,db=dv/y$ so:
$$F(x,y)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u\sin v}{u/x+v/y}\frac{du}{x}\frac{dv}{y}=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u\sin v}{yu+xv}du\,dv$$
makes the sines simpler but we are probably going to have to use another system I think

---

$$F(x,y)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(xa)\sin(yb)}{a+b}da\,db$$
we could try $u=a+b, v=a-b$ we just have to make sure the jabobian is non-zero:
$$da\,db=\left|\frac{\partial(a,b)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|du\,dv$$
we can work out that:
$$a=\frac{u+v}{2}$$
$$b=\frac{u-v}{2}$$
and so:
$$\left|\frac{\partial(a,b)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}\frac12 & \frac12 \\ \frac12 &-\frac12\end{matrix}\right|=-\frac12$$
$$da\,db=-\frac12du\,dv$$
so our integral will become:
$$F(x,y)=-\frac12\iint\limits_S\frac{\sin\left(\frac x2(u+v)\right)\sin\left(\frac y2(u-v)\right)}{u}dudv$$
Now you need to separate $u,v$ using compound angle rule and work out the domain $S$